# How setup mysqli in BitBucket pipelines

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to implement BitBucket piplines to my project and I have problem with install extension mysqli. My configuration is

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - php vendor/bin/tester -p php --setup "tests/inc/setup.php" "tests/cases/"
        services:
          - mysql

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'test'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpass'
```

All steps did complete but when test framework starts, all tests failed by error

> Error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Do I have to enable it in php.ini? Or install it by another way?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You have to add the mysql-client and then tell it to use the extension. This is the pipeline that's working for me:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      name: php-56-mysql-latest
      image: php:5.6-apache
  script:
    # install dependancies and mysql client
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip mysql-client

    # enable the mysqli extension
    - docker-php-ext-install mysqli

    # install composer
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - composer -V
    - composer config -g github-oauth.github.com 9351b824c3e8f8fea61c0349f9b6aed8295878a8
    - composer install --no-interaction --no-progress --prefer-dist

    # fake sendmail so emails don't bomb
    - ln -s /bin/true /usr/sbin/sendmail

    # run your composer tests
    - composer test
  services:
    - mysql

definitions:
 services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:latest
     environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: test
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```